# $100$ people have $100$ one-dollar bills. Some give bills to others until all have different amounts. What's the least number of people to give money?

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, integers

> In a group of $100$ people, each of them has a wallet with $100$ one-dollar bills. Some of them gave one or more dollars to one or more of the others and eventually everyone ended up with a different amount $>0$. What is the least number of people who gave some of their money?

I have started by trying to make $10,000$ as a sum of different integers. One way is $4+6+7+\cdots+141$, which means that $95$ people have given money to others but I don’t think this is the correct approach.

Also tried taking one person's amount and sharing it to others, so for example, $4+5+\cdots+14 = 99$ but again this will take for ever and we won't know if it's the optimal.

Can anybody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: The answer is at most 50, just form 50 pairs, label them from $i=1,2,3.. , 50$ and for the $i^{th}$ group there is a transaction of $i$

Comment: If there were 10 people, each with 10 one-dollar bills, then three of them could give $8+7+6=21=1+2+3+4+5+6$ dollars to six others, and the group would have $\{2,3,4,10,11,12,13,14,15,16\}$ dollars. The solution for 100 people is similar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For everyone to have a different amount of money, everyone (except perhaps one person) has to either give or receive some money. Without loss of generality we may assume that nobody is both receiving and giving money; if person $A$ receives money from person $B$ and gives money to person $C$, then we get the same result if person $B$ gives money directly to person $C$.

To minimize the number of people giving money, we must maximize the number of people *not* giving money. Every pair of people not giving must receive a different amount of money. To minimize the amount of money given, the first receiver receives $\$0$, the next receiver receives $\$1$, etcetera, until everyone not giving has received money (possibly $\$0$). The total amount received is then
$$0+1+2+\ldots+(n-1),$$
where $n$ is the number of people not giving money. To minimize the number of people giving this amount of money, the first giver gives $\$99$, the next giver gives $\$98$, etcetera, until there is sufficient money to give to everyone.

So now you want to find the maximal positive integer $n$ such that
$$0+1+2+3+\ldots+(n-1)\leq 99+98+97+\ldots+n.$$
The number of people giving money is then $100-n$.

Comment: Yeah this is what I thought would be correct. One remark is that you could also not receive any money (and have $100) and everyone must have at least 1 dollar so you can at most give 99 dollars. But otherwise I think this gives the correct solution.

Comment: @AugustLiu You are right, I had misread the lower bound. I have corrected it. This does allow for one person not receiving or giving any money; I'll see if I can make that clearer.

Comment: Also I think there's a small mistake in the inequality. I think it should be $0+1+2+...+(100-n-1)\leq 99+98+...+(99-n+1)$

Comment: @AugustLiu You are right, very confusing.  It should be correct now, though I've taken $n$ to be the number of people *not* giving money.

Comment: @Servaes thank you very much! So the people giving money is 70?

Comment: @RodrigoCarbajal The first givers give much more than the first receivers receive, so that is clearly wrong. The top comment to your question already illustrated that the number of people giving is at most $50$.

Comment: I get the maximum value of n is 70 using this method. So 100-n = 30 is the answer?

Comment: @Servaes but by solving your inequality, I get n=70

Comment: @RodrigoCarbajal ...which is the number of people not giving money.

Comment: Ok so the people giving money are 30, right? Because you said 50... Am a bit confused!

Comment: I did not say $50$, I said *at most $50$*.